# F9 Break Link Command in Embed

Tags: excel, powerpoint, vba

In powerpoint I have the task of setting up a embedded excel chart that is linked to an outside workbook. I have had issues when I tried to store the workbook as an excel embed and link to it. What works for me every time is to to change each cell reference with the F9 command. As you can imagine this takes forever and is not efficient. I was wondering if there is a way to do this a lot faster. Particularly with a Macro?

The essential problem that I am trying to solve is that we want to link it to an workbook so that it updates instantly. But when we send it to the client we want do not want to send the workbook just the powerpoint with editable embeds.

Comment: Powerpoint 2007+ pretty much fully supports embedded data sheets. IMO, using these is far superior to using OLEObject embedded/linked charts, linked to an external XLS file.  Have you considered attempting to put the relevant data in the embedded worksheet of PowerPoint?  This is not difficult to do.

Answer (score 1):

Link or embed; you can have either but not both.  They're mutually exclusive.

However, you can, I think, still do this:

Insert | Object

Choose an MSGraph object. This will give you a chart from the old-style charting engine and open the chart's data sheet for editing.

Switch to Excel, select and copy the data you want to create the chart from.

Switch back to PPT and with the cursor in the chart's data sheet, choose Edit | Paste Link.

This will link the data from the spreadsheet to the chart.

Users will still be able to edit the chart, though they may get prompted to convert the chart to the new format each time they try (they should refuse, but it's worth trying just for giggles).